# Best way to use 2 languages in website by creating extra tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp, internationalization

I built an website using cakephp. Users can switch between 2 languages(English and Japanese) to access all the pages. 
In my back end database, I want to save data clients (MySQL) in 2 languages. Currently I have 2 approaches:

Approach 1: use 1 table with 2 columns field_en and field_ja
+clients
id | client_name_en |  client_name_ja | others...
2  | Morning        | Asha | ...

Approach 2: use 2 tables, the second table will store the id and the correspond name in 2 languages
+clients 
id | others...

+clients_lang
 [client_id, language_id , client_name]

Row 1: 2 | 1 | Morning

Row 2: 2 | 2 | Asha

Note: 1 is for english, 2 is for japanese.

Which approach is better for my case.

Comment: How about the built-in TranslateBehavior? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html#TranslateBehavior

Comment: Ask yourself...which method would be simplest when you have to add another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below url first

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html

OR

try this

//Internationalizing Your Application

```
<h2><?php echo __('Posts'); ?></h2>

//The default domain is ‘default’, therefore your locale folder would look something like this:

/app/Locale/eng/LC_MESSAGES/default.po (English)
/app/Locale/fre/LC_MESSAGES/default.po (French)
/app/Locale/por/LC_MESSAGES/default.po (Portuguese)


<?php
// App Controller Code.
public function beforeFilter() {
    $locale = Configure::read('Config.language');
    if ($locale && file_exists(VIEWS . $locale . DS . $this->viewPath)) {
        // e.g. use /app/View/fre/Pages/tos.ctp instead of /app/View/Pages/tos.ctp
        $this->viewPath = $locale . DS . $this->viewPath;
    }
}
```

or:

```
<?php
// View code
echo $this->element(Configure::read('Config.language') . '/tos');
```

//Localization in CakePHP

```
<?php
Configure::write('Config.language', 'fre');
?>

<?php
$this->Session->write('Config.language', 'fre');
?>


<?php
class AppController extends Controller {
    public function beforeFilter() {
        Configure::write('Config.language', $this->Session->read('Config.language'));
    }
}
?>
```

///Translating model validation errors

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {

    public $validationDomain = 'validation';

    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
                'length' => array(
                'rule' => array('between', 2, 10),
                'message' => 'Username should be between %d and %d characters'
            )
        )
    )
}
?>

//Which will do the following internal call:

<?php
__d('validation', 'Username should be between %d and %d characters', array(2, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only this two language is bettere the solution one, if the language can be more isn't the best solution.

The approachthat I advise to you is to use the second approach to use the same code into other site and you have only to insert the new language.